# Update parent based on child in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table in the below given format:

| parent | child | exists |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2345 | true |
| 1234 | 3436 | true |
| 1234 | 4355 | true |
| 1234 | 0 | false |
| 1234 | 0 | false |

I would like to write a query which selects and updates the table if all non-zero child of a particular parent has exists = True. If that is the case, I would like to make all the exists for '0' child to 'true'

if even one value of a non-zero child is false, zero child should stay as 'false'.

Here is what I tried:

```
select item,child,
case when child = 0 and exists = 'False' 
and item in (SELECT item 
FROM table t1 
where not EXISTS
( SELECT t2.item 
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t2.item = t1.item and t2.child = t1.child  
    and t2.child <> 0
    and t2.exists = 'True'
  )) 
  then 'True' else exists end exists from (SELECT *
    FROM table 
)
```

Comment: Why does your sample query use a `date` field? What is the `item` field you are using? Is the `exists` column a Boolean or a Text/Varchar?

Comment: @John Rotenstein I edited the query to remove the date field. That is not mandatory. Item is the parent id for the child. Exists is a text field

Comment: Should a parent ever have more than one '0' child?   It looks like you are trying to use the 0 child as a flag for the existence of the other non-zero children, but your test table shows two '0' children for 1234.

Comment: @DarrelLee Yes, a parent can have more than one '0' child. I used 0 child as a flag to differentiate and identify if all non-zero children have 'exists' as True.  If all non-zero children have 'exists' set to 'True', then I would like both the '0' children set to 'True' as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a correlated subquery.

```
select * from dclee.test1 t1;

Update dclee.test1 t1
  set t1."EXISTS" = 'true'
    
    where t1.child = 0 
    and not exists (select 1 from dclee.test1 t2
                    where t1.parent = t2.parent 
                        and t2.child  0 
                        and t2."EXISTS" = 'false')
           and exists (select t3.parent, count(1) nz_cnt
                       from dclee.test1 t3
                       where t1.parent = t3.parent
                       and t3.child != 0
                       group by t3.parent
                       having count(1) > 0);
                        
commit;
            
drop table dclee.test1;

create table dclee.test1 as
select 1234 as Parent, 0 as child, 'false' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all
select 1234 as Parent, 2345 as child, 'true' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all 
select 1234 as Parent, 3436 as child, 'true' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all
select 1234 as Parent, 4355 as child, 'true' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all
select 1235 as Parent, 0 as child, 'false' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all
select 1235 as Parent, 5345 as child, 'true' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all 
select 1235 as Parent, 6436 as child, 'true' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all
select 1235 as Parent, 3436 as child, 'false' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all
select 1236 as Parent, 0 as child, 'false' as "EXISTS" from dual
union all
select 1236 as Parent, 0 as child, 'false' as "EXISTS" from dual
```

Comment: this works for the scenario I mentioned above, but it replaces all "exists" to true when child is 0 if a parent does not have any child. For example, a parent id 1222 having only one record with child 0 having "exists" = False by default. The above query replaces that record as well and sets "exists" to True

Comment: OK.  Updated my answer.   I don't understand why you need more than one 0 child..  Also am just assuming all the 0 child will be set false to begin with.

Comment: OK.  You're suppose mark the answer as accepted, unless you're looking for something better.